# Is it possible for a website to determine whether the user is browsing through a transparent proxy?

Tags: 404, proxy

I'm currently browsing through a local transparent proxy.

I'm receiving 404 responses from a couple of web hosts, although the proxy works perfectly with everything else; I was wondering whether it could be the websites recognizing and blocking the proxy user.

Is this a possibility or is there something wrong with the proxy?

Comment: Big subject, see: http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/detection/detecting-preventing-anonymous-proxy-usage-32943

Comment: It is possible to block known proxies using a black-list at various levels including some web-servers. However, open proxies come and go by the minute. There are servers that test for various proxies as part of unnamed hush-hush security apparatus(s) and that data does get into the black-lists relatively quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question doesn't appear to be about a [website under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and is also fairly broad.